# How to configure the clickhouse 's port - 9004,9005, 9009 to other

Tags: clickhouse

I am working on the clickhouse, it is working well with the ports listening on 9004,9005,9009 and so on.

```
clickhous  15366      clickhouse   57u  IPv4  92503      0t0  TCP localhost:8123 (LISTEN)
clickhous  15366      clickhouse   58u  IPv4  92504      0t0  TCP localhost:9000 (LISTEN)
clickhous  15366      clickhouse   59u  IPv4  92505      0t0  TCP localhost:9004 (LISTEN)
clickhous  15366      clickhouse   60u  IPv4  92506      0t0  TCP localhost:9005 (LISTEN)
clickhous  15366      clickhouse   61u  IPv6  92507      0t0  TCP ip6-localhost:9009 (LISTEN)
clickhous  15366      clickhouse   62u  IPv4  92508      0t0  TCP localhost:9009 (LISTEN)
```

however I have other applications to use the port on 9004,9005 and 9009, how would I reconfigure the existing ports to other ports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the configuration file of your clickhouse. Default path in Linux is `/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml`. Search the port in the xml file and change it.
[image]

There is also an auxiliary configuration file directory`/etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/` ,the configuration options in thethis file can override the same options in the main configuration file(`/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml`). This means that you can change their values or override default settings by defining the same configuration items in the auxiliary configuration file.

update:
don't forget restart clickhouse.